# Using XML for data storage

Tags: jquery, xml, blogs

I was asked to create a faux blog using a pretty locked down content management system. I have no ability to using databases for content storage, so I was toying with the option of using XML for storing data about articles; basic stuff like date, title, excerpt, tags and content and use jQuery to render the pages.

Articles are not going to be very long in length, but are there any pros/cons to creating such an application?

Comment: It's unlikely that this will be a problem for you, but we recently developed a solution like this at my job and ran into a BIG problem because we forgot our production server was load-balanced across six machines. A user would update the XML on one server, then reload, then get confused because their XML was now being served from a different machine and their changes weren't in it. (Finally sort-of solved it by saving to the XML file on the testing server instead, but we all agreed a DB would have been the way to go if we'd been given the choice.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't fancy reinventing the wheel http://www.flatpress.org/ does a fine job.

Here is an interesting discussion regarding ACID compliance in flat file DBS:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=524840

Answer (score 1):

As much as I am a fan of XML, it seems to be a bit of a knee-jerk reaction to use this over any other possible format when it comes to data storage/passing. A good database would always be a preferable solution, but if that's really impossible, just try to avoid dumping everything into a huge XML file. Storing a separate file per article with your required metadata (date, title, tags...) would be a good start. Alternatively, the article contents could be embedded in the XML. It would feel right at home with that since XML was initially intended for defining markup languages, even though it seems that these days you find it being used for data structure more often.

Many smaller XML files and then maybe another one that does some indexing would be the way to go. This at least gets somewhere near the partitioning and indexing that goes on in a database. Whatever you do, *don't create one or several huge XML documents*. Otherwise you'll be back here one day asking one of those "help I've gotta parse a 1 GiB XML document and running out of memory" questions :)

Hunter.ross' suggestion looks very fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use XML for your storage purpose but it's going to expensive not that implementation is hard.

As you have not mentioned your platform, I am assuming you are working on .NET! using `XElement`, XML usage is not hard to complicated than just database queries.

On the other hand, the thing you want to achieve is will hit big time on your performance. Your XML files will be rewritten every-time you want to save something and same goes to retrieval, if you are not considering loading your whole XML file in memory. If you do, you will soon get **"Out of memory"** exception once your XML files starts getting bigger.

Implementation cost using XML is relatively high as you have to go through the manual process of how you are going to fetch retrieve data from your XML where a simple database query will do the same.

If you consider any other choice than XML, I would recommend you go with `SQLite`, and you may also read [when to use SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). You don't need any database installation and it's portable. Its just a binary file stored on your server and SQLite has API for almost every platform and it has wide range of wrappers. It's more like executing database queries on your data file.

SQLite is just another relational database like SQL Server, MySQL etc and you can perform your all sorts of SQL queries you know of, and you also can use along with `Entity Framework`, `NHibernate` or any other `ORMs`.

The performance isn't going to be like SQL Server/MySQL but you can server thousands of your site's visitor with this SQLite.